# Winform C# Error provider is not clearing itself despite the SetErrorProvider was appended with empty string

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

The error provider i set for the username is not clearing itself properly. What i understand from my research is that if the SetErrorProvider was appended with an empty string, the error will be cleared itself. However, this does not work in my case. I am using Winform C# and here is my example code.

```
    private void usernamet_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(usernamet.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "Username cannot contain special characters.");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            errorProvider.Clear();
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, "");
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, null);
            errorProvider.SetError(usernamet, string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

i have set 4 breakpoints for each example solution i retrieved from my research, however the error is not clearing itself as shown in the pictures.

[Breakpoint 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5lXd.png)

[Breakpoint 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAu8t.png)

[Breakpoint 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2XDX.png)

[Breakpoint 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSQyT.png)

[Error is not clearing itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DsWJ.png)

Comment: This is a niche library, I'd be asking the authors. Either that or download the code and debug it

Comment: That's you're problem: `ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();`. You're creating a **new Instance**, not related with the existing ErrorProvider object. Remove it. -- BTW; One of the main reasons to use an ErrorProvider is to avoid the Validating Event's `Cancel` Property. So, don't mix these two. @TheGeneral .Net's System.Windows.Forms is not that niche of a library :)

Comment: In case you haven't added an ErrorProvider Component - from the ToolBox - or you haven't declared an ErrorProvider Field object yourself, then do that first.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, it works. I moved the ErrorProvider errorProvider = new ErrorProvider(); outside the validating method. How do you know it is not related to the existing ErrorProvider object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.